# Recover VBA Code in Corrupted Access 2002 Database

Tags: ms-access, vba, corrupt, data-recovery

So somehow my Access database got corrupted and I am trying to recover the VBA code. Does anyone know how to recover the code?

Error message is as follows: "The Visual Basic for Applications project in the database is corrupt."

I think it was caused by someone opening the file on a SP3 machine and then me opening it on a SP2 machine. Not positive though.

Thanks in advance,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that your database is nessessarily corrupt. This occurs when a database/project is compiled using Access 2003 and you try opening it in Access 2002. If you upgrade your Access to the current version, you should be able to solve this issue.

If it's urgent, I suggest you try downloading the trial version of the recent version of Access and try getting at the VBA code from there.